# Open multiple files from ranger in vim

Tags: vim, ranger

When I highlight multiple files in ranger from the same dir, I can open them all in vim with `r` and than `0` or `@` and than add `vim`. But if I highlight files from different dirs, than this doesn't work. Any ideas why and how to get it working?

Bonus question: I would like to open all files with vims `-o` flag (to split vertical), but that doesn't work either, not even on files in the same dir.

Comment: It works for me in Linux with vim version 7.4. It opens the files in the same  directory in split mode

Answer (score 3):

> To copy/move multiple files, just mark them with Space then use
>   "dd/yy". If you want to operate on multiple files stored in different
>   directories, you may use "ya/da" to add them to the list of files to
>   be copied/moved before pasting them.
>
> (Note that the copy/cut buffers can be used for other operations as
>   well, by using the "%c" macro in your commands. For example, adding
>   files to the cut/copy buffer using "ya"/"da" then using the :shell -w
>   printf %c | xargs rm command allows you to delete multiple files in
>   multiple directories. Remember to clear the buffer once you're done
>   using "ud"/"uy".)

So add the files with `ya` and then use a mapping like `xv`:

```
map xv shell vim %c
```

Answer (score 0):

A quick solution without having to use mappings:
Having highlighted the files (with `space` or `V`), just hit `@` and type `vim -o`. This should take you into the ranger shell looking as below:

```
:shell vim -o %s
```

Pressing enter will open vim in split pane mode.